# comma after as and before and grammatical or not?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> I think the claim that this man is guilty of murder is absolutely
> false, as people have been giving false testimonies as of late, and a
> lot of evidences suggest that there's more to what was shown in the
> court.

Can we separate and with a comma even though we're giving a second reason as to why "the claim is false"?

Comment: *A lot of* ***evidences suggest*** is wrong. It should be *a lot of* ***evidence suggests***.

Comment: Where is it from? Presumably what was shown in the court was evidence. So it says __a lot of the evidence suggests there's more to the evidence__. Is that what the writer intended? Also, I'd make it 'of late': not '**as** of late'.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 2nd comma is not required.
The 1st comma should be removed as the independent clause precedes its dependent clause.

My suggestions is:
'I think the claim that this man is guilty of murder is absolutely false as people have been giving false testimonies as of late and a lot of evidence suggests that there's more to what was shown in the court.'